# PHP: In the $_FILES superglobal, is the 'size' element supplied by the client?

Tags: php

I have created a nifty class for sanitizing inputs based on their source using [PHP filter functions](http://php.net/manual/en/book.filter.php), but there is no `INPUT_FILES` for `filter_input_array()`.

Obviously, the routine for checking out a file is very involved and that is not the focus of this question (so, you can skip the php.ini, examine the file, copy the file, don't use the user supplied file name, tricks of the trade stuff, references to the manual, etc).

I simply want to know, what is the source of the value for the `size` element in the `$_FILES` superglobal array. Yes, I still perform tests on it (and the actual file), but I would like to know the origin of the value. The origin of the 'key' is obviously PHP.

A YouTube video on [file upload progress bars](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=EraNFJiY0Eg) (8:50 - 9:10) shows a JavaScript method of determining the file size on the client. If that is true, the file size can definitely come from the user agent and then passed on to the web server / PHP via headers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, the `size` is provided by the server, but the mime-type (`type`) is provided by the client, so don't trust this value and check for yourself.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it's provided for every file. See http://php.net/manual/en/features.file-upload.php

Comment: That is not an answer to the question. Client or server?

Comment: he said client - which is the correct answer. Never trust this value!

Comment: He did not say client.

Comment: Php will make calculation for the size base on POST data.

Comment: @NormanM Why shouldn't it be trusted? The (HTTP) client has to indicate somehow how long the uploaded file is, otherwise the server can't know when the request is completed.

Comment: oh - seems like in newer versions PHP seems to ignore the header where the file size is coming from - but only if the file uploaded is uploaded correctly.